# Appstore description in Multiple Languages

Tags: localization, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an iPhone app and I would like to localize the description that appears in the AppStore.

1) My app in itself **is not localized** and all the strings, resources are in English. The "Binary DEtails" shows "(English)" in Localization. 
2) We have added new languages from the iTunesConnect. Japanese is one of them.

Now, To test this from my iPhone, I changed  "Settings -> Languages" to Japanese. Now searching in AppStore, this still shows my app in English. The "Languages" property on the left also shows only English.

Thanks,
Jarsj

Comment: Just a tip from a professional localizer: putting your app description in Japanese is misleading to the consumer, who will then in turn expect the app to have Japanese text.

Comment: descriptions are always in english.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that changing the language of your phone does not change the appStore you are in. So try to use iTunes (on a Mac / PC) and change the store there.

Also the description is NOT always in English! You can of course add different languages for the appStore description in iTunes-Connect -> Manage Apps -> choose your app -> choose current / next version -> under "Metadata and Uploads" you can choose different languages to translate your description on the right side. Simply add them and then go ahead typing

Hope that helps ;)